# scala implicit par makes no progress

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

This is my first attempt with using Scala's parallelism. I have huge data (that can be stored as any collection) which I would like to parallelize on a multi-core system using a simple map operation (such as `val out = data.par.map(foo(_)`). The example I saw given at [scala docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) has the following snippet that gave weird output. The 'serial' versions seems to run with implicit parallelism and the parallel versions are not working. Any pointers towards a solution would be very much appreciated.

```
scala> val list = (1 to 1000000).toList
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...   // used > 1000% cpu

scala> val out = list.map(_ + 42)          // again used > 1000% cpu
out: List[Int] = List(43, 44, 45, 46, 

scala> val out = list.par.map(_ + 42)      // process stalls, consumes no cpu!

scala> (1 to 10) map println               // initially used >400% cpu
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

scala> (1 to 10).par map println               // process stalls, consumes no cpu!
```

I am using `Scala 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_275)`

Edit: The above code ran in a script but not in scala shell. Probably some limitation of the shell itself.

Comment: The parallel collections do not work very well in the **REPL**, try with a real project. There is a flag to fix the problem in the **REPL** but I do not remember which one it was.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was with the spark-shell only, not the script. I realized that later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`-Yrepl-class-based`](https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections/issues/34)

```
$ scala-runners/scala --scala-version 2.12.10 -Yrepl-class-based
Welcome to Scala 2.12.10 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 10.0.2).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> (1 to 10).par map println
6
9
8
1
10
7
2
3
4
5
res0: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Unit] = ParVector((), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ())
```